# fetching list of races

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in MySQL world.  I have two tables in a database:

1. user_info
2. race_info

In both tables I have common fields location, age, gender, level.

**My question is that how to get the list of those races which are having**

**1**. same level or may not  AND

**2**. same gender or may not

**3**. age of current logged in user may belong to age range like 0-20/30-40 or not
    age saved in race_info table's age field as 0-20, 0-20/30-40, but in user_info table's age field
    only integer like 23

**4**. location of user must be same or not with races location.  For example, suppose there is an race having 
    id=1, for location India, then only Indians can join this race having id=1.

**race_info table**

```
id     gender      level        age           location
1          m       Level 1      0-20/30-40    India/MP
2          f       any level    60-70         England
```

**user_info**

```
id      gender      level          age            location
1          m        Level 1         40            India/MP
2          f        any level       70            England
```

Please provide your kind help to me.

Comment: firslty i get list of those races from race_info table using this $qry = "SELECT * FROM wp_races_info WHERE (level = '$level' OR level = 'Any Level') AND (gender = '$gender' OR gender = 'Any'); after that i do not know how to procee next or get race list fitered according to age and location

Comment: Your question doesn't clearly state what you are trying to achieve.  Update it with the table structure, queries that you have tried and the sample result list like what you want if you are looking for an answer. In the meantime, there are so many keywords in mysql including `group by`, `order by`,`and` etc. which you can learn and try

Comment: race_info table

|id|    |gender|     |level|       |age|        |location|
 
 1          m        Level 1     0-20/30-40         India/MP
 2          f        any level    60-70              England
 
 
 
 user_info
 
 |id|    |gender|     |level|       |age|          |location|
 
 1          m        Level 1         40            India/MP
 2          f        any level       70            England

Comment: What is the meaning of the 'or may not' that appears against criteria 1 and 2?  It is not obvious.  Ditto the 'or not' in crtieria 3 and 4.  Your coding for age ranges is also about as difficult to manage as it could possibly be.  What happened to the 21-29 year old racers in India?  Are you seeking one query, or four queries, or what?

Comment: Smells like database class homework. Please add homework tag if so.